# modular_cloud_matcher compilation error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Trying to get extrinsics between a kinect camera and a robot, I've compiled libpointmatcher and libnao and finally compiling **Automatic Calibration of Extrinsic Parameters** from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Automatic%20Calibration%20of%20Extrinsic%20Parameters)

However [modular_cloud_matcher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/modular_cloud_matcher) is complaining about a missing member in ICPSequence class in the Core.cpp of pointmatcher library.

---

/home/cogx/code/ros/ros mapping/modular_cloud_matcher/src/modular_cloud_matcher_bag.cpp:351:27: **error: ‘struct MetricSpaceAligner::ICPSequence’ has no member named ‘hasKeyFrame’**

---

I guess this is due to a change in the API.

How should one proceed? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10557/modular_cloud_matcher-compilation-error/) by [Alper Aydemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/119/alper-aydemir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is now fixed by Stephane Magnenat, git pull to get the changes in libpointmatcher library.

---

Originally posted by [Alper Aydemir](https://answers.ros.org/users/119/alper-aydemir/) with karma: 126 on 2011-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0